# Richfaces a4j:include loading two pages?

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, richfaces, java-ee-6, ajax4jsf

I have this seemingly-innocent code on my main JSF page:

```
<a4j:outputPanel id="sidebarContainer">
     <a4j:include viewId="#{UserSession.currentSidebar}"/>
</a4j:outputPanel>
```

Here is how the sidebar changes:

1. A jsFunction calls a backing-bean method which sets the page (like "sidebar2.jsp") in UserSession
2. The jsFunction has "rerender='sidebarContainer'", so that the correct page is loaded in the sidebar

When the web application is initially started in JBoss 5, when I call the jsFunction to change pages, sidebar2 appears, but the original sidebar (sidebar1.jsp) appears below it.

The sidebar switching works just fine after this initial wierdness.  Any thoughts??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What seems to be the problem was that another AJAX request is happening at the same time that the AJAX request was called to change sidebars.  We're putting in a few workarounds for now.

I noticed in the notes for RichFaces 4 alpha 2 that since RichFaces4 uses the JSF 2 f:ajax functionality, basically, AJAX requests are serialized so that only one can be underway at any given moment.  So when we move to RichFaces 4 our problem should be solved.